kotlin-exposed DB lib: insert using Potgresql 'inet' type
Starting out with Exposed & Postgresql.
No issues creating table objects, connecting to db, and executing queries. But I'm not sure how to deal with Postgresql-specific types.
I have an inet col named 'sender-ip', and tried to insert using an IP address as String
IPList.insert {
    it[sender_ip] = "127.0.0.1"
}

But, get error on insert:
Exception in thread "main" org.jetbrains.exposed.exceptions.ExposedSQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "sender_ip" is of type inet but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

From reading Exposed docs, I see there's a way to write and execute raw SQL. But, is there a better way to handle this type?

try this
class InetColumnType : StringColumnType() {
    override fun sqlType(): String = "INET"

    override fun setParameter(stmt: PreparedStatementApi, index: Int, value: Any?) {
        val parameterValue: PGobject? = value?.let {
            PGobject().apply {
                type = sqlType()
                this.value = value as? String
            }
        }
        super.setParameter(stmt, index, parameterValue)
    }
}
fun Table.inet(name: String): Column<String> = registerColumn(name, InetColumnType())

and you can use it in your table like below
val ip = inet("sender_ip")

